# Why I was getting Buffer overflow (runtime error)

Tags: c

**Question:**

Given an integer numRows, return the first numRows of Pascal's triangle.
In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it

** Example of 5 row pascal triangle:**
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]

/**
**Code should include:**

- Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
- The sizes of the arrays are returned as *returnColumnSizes array.
- **Note**: Both returned array and *columnSizes array must be malloced,
  assume caller calls free().
  */

**Error I was getting :**
Address Sanitizer::Stack-Buffer-overflow.

**Why I am getting this error?**

**Answer that I did:**

```
 int** generate(int numRows, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){
    int **p=(int**)malloc(numRows*sizeof(p));
    *returnSize=numRows;
    int i=0, j;
    *returnColumnSizes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numRows);
    for(i=0;i<numRows;i++)
    {
        p[i]=(int*)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(int));
        p[i][0]=1;
        if(i>=1)
        {
            p[i][i]=1;
        }
        
        for(j=1;j<=i-1;j++)
        {
            p[i][j]=p[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1][j];
        }
        *returnColumnSizes[i]=i+1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

**Error :**
Address Sanitizer::Stack-Buffer-overflow

Comment: Please [edit] and show how you call `generate`. We need a [mcve]. Also I wonder what the purpose of `*returnSize=numRows` is; you inconditionally assign ``numRows` to this, so it is useless.

Comment: the type of `p` is `int**`, and you allocate memory for multiple `int**`s due to the `sizeof(p)`
It may work but it is an error, you want to allocate for multiple `int*`. Therefore you should use `sizeof(int*)`